# deploying private git repo with pass phrase using chef open source server

Tags: ubuntu, github, amazon-web-services, ssh, chef-infra

I am trying to deploy from a private github/bitbucket account which holds a pass phrase on ubuntu ec2 instance. By quick googling I am landed up on blogs, websites but no blog or websites suggesting how to config with pass pharse. Any heads up will help me a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automated authenticated ssh/git operations almost never use interactive (password) authentication. Passwordless ssh keys are used. See the following directions for setting up a deploy key for Github:
https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys

Then follow the rest of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18495349/1342791

For more information on how to use the chef deploy resource, see here: http://docs.opscode.com/resource_deploy.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can do that. The usual way is to use a deploy key on the repository. If you don't mind the shameless plug, I created a cookbook called [`deploy_key`](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/deploy_key) that manages such keys on both BitBucket and Github.

It supports creating a key on the server, adding to the repo and deleting from the repo.