# Checkout git repo with chef with ssh key

Tags: git, ssh, chef-infra

Hello I am having issues getting chef to checkout my git repo using an ssh key from my data_bag.

Below is my git resource:

```
repo_key = search(:git, "id:git_key").first
git_key_file = "#{Chef::Config['file_cache_path']}/git_key/id_rsa"

directory "#{Chef::Config['file_cache_path']}/git_key" do
    action :create
end

file git_key_file do
    content repo_key['deploy_key']
    mode "0755"
    action :create_if_missing
end

git "/usr/share/my_repo" do
    repository "git@github.com:my_name/some_repo.git"
    checkout_branch "#{node["my_app"][:test_branch]}"
    action :sync
    ssh_wrapper "ssh -i #{git_key_file}"
end
```

When I run: `sudo chef-client` I get the error below:

```
STDERR: error: cannot run ssh -i /var/chef/cache/git_key/id_rsa: No such file or directory
```

I have ssh'ed into the server and I can verify that the key file is in the proper place and contains the key.

Comment: What happens when you run that command manually on your server?

Comment: The same exact thing happens.

Comment: So, how is this a problem with Chef? Running the ssh command manually on the server fails, so of course this will fail when executed by Chef. Have you looked at the man pages for `ssh -i`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes I have looked at the man pages and the -i is to point to an identity file which I am doing and I have verified that the identity file is correct. I'm starting to think it may be a permissions issue and that I shouldn't be using 0755.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While your private-key file may be in the right place, my [limited] understanding is that the `GIT_SSH` variable must be the path to an executable script rather than a command itself.

Thankfully, there is a much easier way to set-up Git to use a particular SSH key per repository that doesn't rely on setting environmental variables or creating new scripts. The general process is described in [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/943533/9110), which is to specify the custom SSH command as an "external transport" in the repository location. Here is how I use the method in a Chef recipe:

```
# Add a deployment key to the node from chef-vault, e.g. at 
#    /path/to/some_repo_deployment_key
#    /path/to/some_repo_deployment_key.pub

git "/usr/share/my_repo" do
  # The following line ensures that our repo-specific deployment 
  # ssh-key will be used for all clone & fetch operations.
  repository "ext::ssh -i /path/to/some_repo_deployment_key -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no git@github.com %S /my_name/some_repo.git"
  checkout_branch "master"
  action :sync
end
```

After the repository has been cloned, `git fetch` and `git push` operations from within the working-directory will used the same key, making further automation more independent of environmental setup than some of the other techniques which rely on `ssh`'s key-discovery mechanisms.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me except I was getting `STDERR: fatal: Cannot force update the current branch.` error while the line `checkout_branch`was existing. Once I've removed it, no problem at all!

Comment: Just a note, this works nicely with the `deploy_revision` chef resource.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you found the answer to this (too open of permissions) but here is the relevant info from my ssh man page:

```
 ...
 ~/.ssh/identity
 ~/.ssh/id_dsa
 ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
 ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
         Contains the private key for authentication.  These files contain sensitive data and should be readable by the user but not accessible by others (read/write/execute).
         ssh will simply ignore a private key file if it is accessible by others.  It is possible to specify a passphrase when generating the key which will be used to encrypt the sensitive part of this file using 3DES.
```

Comment: Yea after permissions it still has the same error. I ended up just giving up and adding a gradle build task to archive the test scripts and deploy to an S3 bucket then I have Chef download the latest archive and extract it.

Comment: Did you try setting restricted permissions on the parent folder `/var/chef/cache` as well?  The permissions on the folder should be 700 and the permissions on the key should be 400

Comment: That I did not try, but I will give it a whirl and see what happens. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this problem by, running following:

GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/bitbucket_rsa"

On chef recipe adding something like this:

```
execute 'git ssh' do
  command 'GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/#{rsa['name']}"'
  user "centos"
end
```

Reference and for my whole steps can be found at my blog: http://www.sadafnoor.com/blog/simplest-way-to-write-your-chef-cookbook-that-git-clone-private-repo-using-bitbucket-deploy-key/